# GET request processed as HTML rather than TURBO_STREAM from within turbo_frame_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I am starting to work with hotwire/turbo and have set everything up.
Turbo streams are working correctly.

Within index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<%= turbo_stream_from "tasks" %>

<div id="tasks">
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <%= render task %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Within _task.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(task) do %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <hr>
<% end %>
```

When the destroy button is pressed as expected, rails console says:

```
Started DELETE "/tasks/41" for ::1 at 2021-12-14 18:40:32 +0000
Processing by TasksController#destroy as TURBO_STREAM
```

But when pressing the edit button, rails console says:

```
Started GET "/tasks/41/edit" for ::1 at 2021-12-14 18:41:29 +0000
Processing by TasksController#edit as HTML
```

This means the page loads a new page, rendering edit.html.erb rather than just updating the content within the turbo_frame_tag.

When inspecting the DOM, both the edit and destroy links are within a turbo-frame:

```
<turbo-frame id="task_41">
  <a href="/tasks/41/edit">Edit</a>
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/tasks/41">Destroy</a>
  <hr>
</turbo-frame>
```

So my question is, why does the request get processed as HTML and not TURBO_STREAM ?

edit.html.erb looks like this:

```
<h1>Editing Task</h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@task) do %>
    <%= render 'form', task: @task %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Show', @task %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_path %>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

In application.js, I still had this line:

```
require("turbolinks").start()
```

I removed this, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and my application doesn't have a `require("turbolinks").start()` line to remove.

In addition, I feat that when removing that line, *every other link_to will be processed as a `turbo_stream`.* And at any point on the development of the application, one will need a `link_to` that will act as HTML.

Comment: You can also try adding `method: :get` to your `link_to` tags.  I know they are already get but this trick worked for me.

Comment: I found I needed to add import Rails from "@rails/ujs" and Rails.start() to my application.js file to get the links to work with turbo_stream for get requests. Remember to do yarn add @rails/ujs.